# Catchable fatal error - Joomla Compoent - FOF

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I Newly Create Joomla Component using Framework on Framework. Administrator Section Working Fine. In Site Section Display Following Error. How to Resolve this **Error**.

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to FOFTable::setInput() must
>   be an instance of FOFInput, instance of F0FInput given, called in
>   /var/www/testjoomla/libraries/f0f/table/table.php on line 434 and
>   defined in /var/www/testjoomla/libraries/fof/table/table.php on line
>   3236

in my Dispatcher code :

```
include_once JPATH_LIBRARIES.'/fof/include.php';
class GulfJobDispatcher extends FOFDispatcher
{
    public function onBeforeDispatch() {
        $result = parent::onBeforeDispatch();

        if($result) {
            // Load Akeeba Strapper
            include_once JPATH_ROOT.'/media/akeeba_strapper/strapper.php';
            AkeebaStrapper::bootstrap();
            AkeebaStrapper::jQueryUI();
            AkeebaStrapper::addCSSfile('media://com_gulfjob/css/frontend.css');
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change F0F to FOF in your Controller or Other Area